# AngularJs 1.6 ui-router not loading local content

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I have a frustrating problem.. yesterday I created a simple skeleton page for starting an angularJS app. It loads several common items (header, sidebar) using ui-router. It was working beautifully yesterday, and today, I attempt to load the page and keep working on my project and nothing. Total blank page. All the content for the project is being loaded locally.

I've tried two different browsers, FF and chrome, and in neither browser do I get any errors in the console.

Here's my code for review.

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ngSearchApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/styles.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <div id="contentWrapper">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div data-ui-view="header"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div data-ui-view="main"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div data-ui-view="sideBar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**partial-header.html & partial-sidebar.html**

```
<img src="/path/to/image" />
```

**app.module.js**

```
'use strict';

var ngSearchApp = angular.module('ngSearchApp', ['ui.router']);

ngSearchApp.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
     $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
           url: '/',
            template: '',
            views: {
                'header': {
                    //controller: 'headerCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'app/shared/header/partial-header.html'
                    },
                'main': {
                 //controller: 'mainCtrl',
                 templateUrl: 'app/components/search/partial-main.html'
                 },
                 'sideBar': {
                 //controller: 'sidebarCtrl',
                 templateUrl: 'app/shared/sidebar/partial-sidebar.html'
                 },
             }
       });
   }]);
```

**controller.js**

```
 //Controllers
 ngSearchApp.controller('searchBtnCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
 }]);

 ngSearchApp.controller('resultsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
 }]);
```

At the moment, the header and sidebar html files just have placeholder images.

So this is baffling to me why this would work just fine yesterday when I use the view in firefox function out of visual studio, but today, absolutely nothing. I've also cleared my cache multiple times but still no joy.

It feels like it's just skipping over the stateProvider and not bothering to load any of the views.. but that's just a guess. I'd appreciate any more educated suggestions.

Thanks!